# Is there a importance of the connected peers?

Tags: go-ethereum, mining, peers

I'm a pool dev, and I'm asking some questions about peers connected to node.

- What is the "best" number of connected peers ? I guess too less or too much connected is important ?
- Is there a "peer quality" ? Should I pick and reject some ? like filter by client version or difficulty ... to improve the mining quality ?

Thank you !

Comment: the best number of peers depends. When I was syncing archival node over DSL connection at home I set maxpeers to 2 because I needed minimal amount of network traffic so I can watch youtube videos without delay. But if you are frontrunning transactions you need to set maxpeers to 500 so you get the data from the network as quickly as possible

Comment: The node is used for mining, So I guess the more I have peers, the better is right ?

Comment: you are a bit late for mining, we have been mining since 2015 and now in August with entering PoS era, lots of miners will be looking for other coins

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Connected peers are used to fetch and broadcast data.

A1 : the connected peer count is not a big deal if you know the quality of the peer node. a 1 node with the best hardware is better than 10 nodes in china running on dual-core PCs. So your best bet is to have the best nodes connected. Also having 200 peers on your node when you are running on low-end hardware is useless as you are not going to utilize that number efficiently.

A2 : The `geth` node AFAIK doesn't have peer quality review built-in, but would try to look for new peers if some peers would stop responding or have multiple timeouts. For actively looking for best quality nodes, you will need to find those on your own by querying them externally and rating them outside the node.